# expand json in a pandas columns to the whole dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column that contains json values. like below:

```
  json_col 
0     {"name":"John","role":"manager", "age":40}     
1     {"name":"Mary","role":"director", "age":50}
```

How can I expand the key into the columns of the pandas dataframe with the corresponding values?

Desired result:

```
  name       role      age 
0 John      manager    40
1 Mary      director   50
```

Comment: kindly share your source dataframe as a dictionary : ``df.to_dict('records')``

Answer (score 1):

Use [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[{"name": "John", "role": "manager", "age": 40}],
                        [{"name": "Mary", "role": "director", "age": 50}]], columns=["json_col"])

res = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df["json_col"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   name      role  age
0  John   manager   40
1  Mary  director   50
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. I am getting this error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Perhaps if you add some data of your dataframe just like I did in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.loads`:

```
import json

out = df['json_col'].apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series)
print(out)

# Output:
   name      role  age
0  John   manager   40
1  Mary  director   50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to expand the column into a dataframe, as follows:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df['json_col'].tolist())
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


   name      role  age
0  John   manager   40
1  Mary  director   50
```